# Locking sheet or multiple tabs in sheet in Google Sheets at a specific time and unlock it after

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to code my Google Sheets sheet or multiple tabs in a sheet in a way that it automatically locks at a specific time every day and unlock it on specific time every day. Also I should be able to edit it, but not my collaborators.

How do I pull this off?

Thank you!

Comment: Quick question: why do you need to lock it, if you'll be the only one able to edit the spreadsheet? You can always share the sheet with _view only_ privileges.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to go ahead.
The simplest is probably to add and remove your collaborators:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  
  //set the hours in which you want the document to be edited
  var starttime = 8
  var endtime = 18

  //instead Europe/Berlin (your place)
  var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/Berlin", "H")

  //adds a collaborator
  if (now >= starttime && now <= endtime){
    ss.addEditor("xxx@gmail.com")
  }

  //removes a collaborator & optionally gives him viewing rights 
  else{
   ss.removeEditor("xxx@gmail.com")
   //ss.addViewer("xxx@gmail.com")
  }
}
```

Now run your code every hour with a trigger and it will do the rest by itself.

Comment: Thank you for this, I try and give you a feedback. This is a big help